# how do i get controller value to template file

Tags: magento-1.9, template, collection

I am going to create reward point extension in which the calculation of grand total are in my module controller and now I want to show the final value at the place of grand total for that I want to implement **grandtotal.phtml**

at **line 55**

```
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
    <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()+10) ?></strong>
</td>
```

**I Want to put value instead of 10 from my controller which are in *different* module so how can i put this value.**

Answer (score 0):

Store your calculate value into register. Put following code into controller.

```
$customValue = 20;
Mage::register('custom_value', $customValue);
```

Now you can get value using **Mage::registry('custom_value')**. So your code looks like:

```
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
    <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()+Mage::registry('custom_value')) ?></strong>
</td>
```

Comment: I tried but not working